# Fundamentals: KVL in this AC circuit doesn't add up

Tags: voltage, power, resistors, ac, kirchhoffs-laws

I've got the following circuit:

[image]

And with it the following meter readings:

[image]

In the condition RL, the capacitor has a short over top of it and in RC the inductor has a short over top of it.

My question is this: Why does it seem that the voltage across the components in each condition never adds up to the supplied voltage (100V). I know current for the resistor will be phase with the voltage, inductor will be 90 degrees lagging and the capacitor will be 90 degrees leading. So say if it came to KCL I'd have to use phasor addition instead of just adding the magnitudes. I'm assuming there's something similar at work here? Would I be wrong in saying that the angle of voltage across all components here will be the same? What's the trick?

Thanks, and sorry for the noob question.

EDIT: The resistance here is 300 ohms, cap is 2.2 mic, and inductor is 0.8 H

Comment: "the angle of voltage across all components here will be the same" is meaningless because you haven't include a reference vector. (Angle between what and what ?)

Comment: @LongPham Assuming here all same frequency and voltage is reference with an angle of 0 degrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would I be wrong in saying that the angle of voltage across all
>   components here will be the same?

Yes you would be wrong. The only common factor for series connected components is the current and this MUST have the same phase angle and amplitude common to all components.

The voltage across the capacitor is 180 degrees out of phase with the voltage across the inductor so, the net voltage (if you'd measured it) across L and C together is: -

126.3 - 32.57 = 93.73 volts.

And that net reactive voltage is at 90 degrees to the resistor voltage (30.86 volts) hence, if you didn't know the full supply voltage you would calculate it as: -

$$\sqrt{30.86^2+93.73^2}$$

This equals 98.68 volts and near enough to 100.9 volts given measurement errors, non-perfect inductors and non-perfect capacitors and tolerances on all components.

Answer (score 1):

Current is the same through all components, because it is a series circuit. Voltage is indeed in phase with it across the resistor, and 90 degrees out of phase for C and L. The sum of these voltages is a *phasor* sum, and *these* will add up to the total  Vin.

Basics, but still very easy to get lost/confused with this stuff. Draw yourself a phasor diagram and it should all work out.

(Note that the simple arithmetic sum of the voltages is always a bit more than the input voltages - that's because treating the voltages as phasors always reduces the effective sum.)